# Excel VBA - Using arrays created in another module

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to create a workbook that allows the user to import some sort of master data, import some data you want to compare to the master data, and ultimately do analysis on these data. Both master and imported data could be a workbook (i.e. multiple sheets).

My idea is to group the worksheets into a master sheet array and an imported sheet array, so that I can refer to them in the analysis code. Currently I have managed to create these two arrays in two separate modules (2 click buttons), but then I have no way of using the arrays in a third module.

Is there a way of doing it? or is my thinking wrong to have used this approach in the first place?

the following would be my codes.

```
Sub ImportMaster_Click()

Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String, sSheetName As String
Dim sThisBk As Workbook
Dim wbBk As Workbook
Dim wsSht As Worksheet
Dim vfilename As Variant
Dim Mshtarray()
Dim MshtName As String
Dim lSheetNumber As Long
Dim lshtcount As Long
Dim iMshtcount As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

'import data that you want to compare with master data

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook
sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Open File")
If sImportFile = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
    Exit Sub
Else
    vfilename = Split(sImportFile, "\")
    sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename))
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sImportFile


    Set wbBk = Workbooks(sFile)

    With wbBk
        lSheetNumber = wbBk.Worksheets.Count
        If lSheetNumber > 1 Then

           x = 0
            For iMshtcount = 1 To lSheetNumber
                x = x + 1
                ReDim Preserve Mshtarray(0 To iMshtcount)
                Mshtarray(x) = wbBk.Sheets(x).Name

            Next

            If IsArray(Mshtarray) = True Then

                For y = 1 To x
                    If Mshtarray(y) <> "Import page" Then
                            lshtcount = sThisBk.Worksheets.Count
                            wbBk.Sheets(Mshtarray(y)).Copy after:=sThisBk.Sheets(lshtcount)


                    End If
                Next
            Else
                MsgBox "Array error"
            End If
            sThisBk.Sheets("Import page").Select

        ElseIf lSheetNumber = 1 Then

            MshtName = ActiveSheet.Name

            If SheetExists(MshtName) Then
                Set wsSht = .Sheets(MshtName)
                wsSht.Copy after:=sThisBk.Sheets("Import page")
            Else
                MsgBox "There is no Sheet with name :  in:" & vbCr & .Name
            End If
            sThisBk.Sheets("Import page").Select

        Else

            MsgBox "Error, no worksheet opened"


        End If


        wbBk.Close SaveChanges:=False



    End With
End If



Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Public Function SheetExists(ByVal sWSName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean

Dim sht As Worksheet
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(sWSName)
On Error GoTo 0
SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing

End Function
```

The module for importing data is similar to the one above. the problem is the third module that I want to compare the data at.

```
Sub Reporting_Click()

Dim wbBk As Workbook
Dim wsSht As Worksheet
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastvisRow As Long
Dim readN3 As Integer
Dim maxN3 As Integer
Dim shtcount As Integer
Dim fltrng As Range
Dim a As Long


Set wbBk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets
'vMshtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Module1.Mshtarray(y)) <----- I have error for calling such array here
'vImshtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Module3.Imshtarray(j))

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each wsSht In wkbk.Worksheets
 shtcount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 Set wsSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets <---- problem for setting worksheets as well since I can see wsSht is still nothing after running this line 


with wsSht
    a = 2
    For a = 2 To a = shtcount <---- ******

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(a).Name <> "Import page" Then

        wsSht.AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = wsSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        wsSht.Range("D6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>="


        Set fltrng = wsSht.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        firstRow = fltrng.Range("E1").End(xlUp).Row
        lastvisRow = fltrng.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row
        readN3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("E" & firstRow, "E" & lastvisRow))
        maxN3 = 0
        If maxN3 < readN3 Then
            maxN3 = readN3
        End If

    Else

        MsgBox "No data available for analysis"
    End If

Next

End With
```

Even when I just want to try the codes within the for loop, VBA can only run to the line with ****** and then directly skipped to end sub. 
Can somebody help me out here please?

Comment: "Set wsSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" - this line doesn't make any sense (it's a syntax error anyway).  What are you trying to do?  Which worksheet are you trying to assigh to wsSht?  "For a = 2 To a = shtcount" - I think you simply mean "For a = 2 To shtcount", your actual line produces a syntax error.

Comment: You are opening two other files in your analysis file, right? If that is true the thisworkbook will always point to the analysis workbook and not the two other files.

Comment: @MichalRosa I was trying to assign a variable as any worksheets within the workbook so that I can run the for loop

Comment: @Andreas nope the files are copied into the workbook that I have written these macros in. This is why I would like to group the copied worksheets into an array of worksheet names that I can later refer to, but I can't figure out how this can be done.

Comment: Why are you coping the workbooks? Why not just open them and refer to them as wb1 and wb2. Then `wb1.sheets("sheet 1").range("A1").value`

Comment: @Andreas this is actually a good question. If I leave the workbooks open then the matter is much simpler. But if I still want to copy them into the same workbook is there any way to do it?

Comment: Sure, but it will be more complex. I would advice to rename the sheets just to make sure they don't have the same name. Say "WB1 sheet 1", "WB1 Total" and so on. Just rename the sheets when you copy them.

Comment: @Andreas the sheets in each imported workbook have different names. However, since the data (the workbooks) is created upon a different object each time, there are slight difference in their naming, e.g. the numbering would be different. This is why I didn't want to specify the worksheet names in the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Control Variable Missing (misused)

I've corrected the errors but I don't know what you are trying to do with the arrays. Try to explain.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Reporting_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wbBk As Workbook
Dim wsSht As Worksheet
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastvisRow As Long
Dim readN3 As Integer
Dim maxN3 As Integer
Dim shtcount As Integer
Dim fltRng As Range
Dim a As Long

'vMshtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Module1.Mshtarray(y)) <----- I have error for calling such array here
'vImshtname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Module3.Imshtarray(j))

Set wbBk = ActiveWorkbook

' shtcount = wbBk.Worksheets.Count
' For a = 2 To shtcount
'     With wbBk.Worksheets(a)
'
'     End With
' Next

' Or
For Each wsSht In wbBk.Worksheets
    With wsSht
        If .Name <> "Import page" Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            .Range("D6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=0", _
                    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>="
            Set fltRng = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            With fltRng.Range("E1")
                firstRow = .End(xlUp).Row
                lastvisRow = .End(xlDown).Row
            End With
            readN3 = Application.WorksheetFunction _
                    .Max(Range("E" & firstRow, "E" & lastvisRow))
            maxN3 = 0
            If maxN3 < readN3 Then
                 maxN3 = readN3
            End If
          Else
            MsgBox "No data available for analysis"
        End If
    End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: @VBasic2008 I need to compare the master worksheets and the imported worksheets. Therefore I would have to refer to the worksheets with their names in the respective arrays, because I was trying to give the flexibility of not needing to know how many sheets the users are importing.